# How to execute the controller when the ajax request is successed?

Tags: java, ajax, spring

I'm trying to when ajax request is successed, make controller api executing. I want to make when kakao api request is successed, execute `session.setAttribute("logStatus", "Y");` but the session object is server object so couldn't be used in jsp's script tag. Add, the objects in loginOK api are not in kakao api but I want to execute only the code `session.setAttribute("logStatus", "Y")` when the kakao api reauest is successed in jsp. How can I amend the codes? Codes are below those are in jsp and controller related with login function.

```
function kakaoLogin() {
    Kakao.Auth.login({
        success: function (response) {
            // Kakao API 
            Kakao.API.request({ 
                url: '/v2/user/me',
                success: function (response) {
                    window.location.href = '/smhrd';
                      $.ajax({
                          // controller mapping
                          url: 'loginOk', 
                          type: 'POST',
                          success: function (data) {
                              console.log(data); 
                              // redirection
                              window.location.href = '/smhrd';
                          },
                          error: function (error) {
                              console.log(error);
                          },
                      });
                },
                fail: function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                },
            });
        },
        fail: function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        },
    });
}
```

```
   @PostMapping("/loginOk")
   public ModelAndView loginOk(String u_id, String u_pw, HttpSession session) {
      UserDTO dto = service.loginOk(u_id, u_pw);
      System.out.println("loginOk 호출성공");
      ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
      
      if(dto != null) {
         session.setAttribute("logId", dto.getU_id());
         session.setAttribute("logName", dto.getU_name());
         session.setAttribute("logStatus", "Y");
         
         mav.setViewName("redirect:/");
      }else {
         mav.setViewName("register/loginResult");
      }
      return mav;
   }
```

And the below is the error(5xx) in server when the function  kakaoLogin() is called. additionally, when I check the result, until the code "url: '/v2/user/me'" is well done but the code "console.log(data)" is not called I think the controller mapping is failed.

```
------the error(5xx)-----
[Request processing failed; nested exception is org.mybatis.spring.MyBatisSystemException: nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not set parameters for mapping: ParameterMapping{property='param1', mode=IN, javaType=class java.lang.Object, jdbcType=null, numericScale=nul`
```

But I'm not sure about is it right to execute the controller 'loginOk' because the objects are in loginOk are not in kakaoAPI so There's no dto when the controller is called.

Comment: I guess you forgot window.location.href = '/smhrd'; in success scenario

Comment: You have two redirection right now. please delete first one maybe it can lead this error.